# select sum grouped records by count

Tags: sql, oledb

I have an excel sheet that contains invoices of orders
Each invoice has the following data

`ID = a unique id for each ID`

`CUSTOMER = The name of the ID`

`AMT = The total value of the invoices`

`DATE = The date of the purchase`

For the following data

```
CID     CUSTOMER    AMT     DATE
1       James           100     1/1/2012
2       Mark            110     1/1/2012
3       John            110     2/1/2012
1       James           200     2/1/2012
3       John            140     2/1/2012
2       Mark            120     3/1/2012
```

I need to select records from excel sheet so that i have this output

```
CID     Customer    INVCOUNT    TotalValue
1       James       2       300     
1       John        2       250     
1       Mark        2       230
```

This is the sql i tried

```
Select
  i.[CID],
  i.[CUSTOMER],
  Count(i.[CID]) as INVCOUNT,
  sum(i.AMT) as TotalValue
From
  [Invoices] i
Where
  i.[DATE] >= #2/1/2012# And
  i.[DATE] <= #3/1/2012#
Group By
  i.[CID], i.[CUSTOMER]
Having
  Count(i.[CID]) > 1
```

pls this is an excel query, not mysql. The tag i used earlier was a mistake.

WHat am i doing wrong?

Comment: I think your first date check is incorrect... Should it not be 1/1/2012?

Comment: What is the result you get from this query? Also with regards to the date, I would expect only John to be displayed, as the others have dates outside your range.

Comment: Your SQL syntax isn't correct for MySQL, that looks like T-SQL.

Comment: Is the date stored in a date type field? Assuming it is and the dates are being correctly compared I would expect a single row back from this query (for john). Although # is normally just used in Access to delimit dates, not MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the output you specified:

```
Select
  1 as CID,
  i.[CUSTOMER],
  Count(i.[CID]) as INVCOUNT,
  sum(i.AMT) as TotalValue
From
  [Invoices] i
Where
  i.[DATE] >= #1/1/2012# And
  i.[DATE] <= #3/1/2012#
Group By
  i.[CID], i.[CUSTOMER]
Having
  Count(i.[CID]) > 1
```

To get the output I think you actually want:

```
Select
  i.[CID],
  i.[CUSTOMER],
  Count(i.[CID]) as INVCOUNT,
  sum(i.AMT) as TotalValue
From
  [Invoices] i
Where
  i.[DATE] >= #1/1/2012# And
  i.[DATE] <= #3/1/2012#
Group By
  i.[CID], i.[CUSTOMER]
Having
  Count(i.[CID]) > 1
```

This should generate

```
CID     Customer    INVCOUNT    TotalValue
1       James       2       300     
2       John        2       250     
3       Mark        2       230
```

Comment: if i need to exclude customers who bought in the dates in you example, but exclude from this list any who also bought in 3/7/2012, can you show me how?